# VBA Runtime Error 1004 the extract range has a missing or invalid field name

Tags: vba, excel

Please, I am getting an error in this part of my macro. It shows me this error:

```
1004 the extract range has a missing or invalid field name
```

In this line:

```vb
Range("'CF Backlog.xls'!DATA").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:B2"), CopyToRange:=Range("C1:BJ1"), Unique:= _
    False
```

Code:

```vb
Sheets("Template").Activate
Range("A1:B2").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Criteria", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=Template!R1C1:R2C2"
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Criteria", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=Template!R1C1:R2C2"
     'Range("C1:BJ1").ClearContents
Range("'CF Backlog.xls'!DATA").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:B2"), CopyToRange:=Range("C1:BJ1"), Unique:= _
    False
```

I have spent many hours checking forums. But, I still can't fix the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: in `CF Backlog.xls` go to the `Name Manager` in the Formulas tab and see if the Name `DATA` is there

Comment: @cyboashu, I rejected your proposed edit as I did not feel you did enough. While what you did was an improvement, you should make all improvements which you reasonably see in one edit. In this case, the minimum that I would have expected was that you make the obvious capitalization changes to have capital letters at the beginning of sentences and change " i " to " I ". Just those significantly improve readability. In this instance (and most of the time), some method to distinguish the error text, usually code format, should be used (quote format can be OK, but is not preferred)

Comment: @azerty, I have made the assumption that the text I indicated as the error text is exactly what was displayed to you as the error. If this is not the case, please [edit] your question to include the exact text displayed. Another time, please indicate that you are providing the exact error text by putting it in code format, quote format, or enclosing it in quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try clearing the destination range

```
Sheets("Template").Activate
Range("A1:B2").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Criteria", RefersToR1C1:= "=Template!R1C1:R2C2"
'ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Criteria", RefersToR1C1:= "=Template!R1C1:R2C2" ' why do you add the same named range two times ??!!
Range("C1:BJ1").ClearContents  ' <-- uncomment this line 
Range("'CF Backlog.xls'!DATA").Select  ' and check if this gives any error
Range("'CF Backlog.xls'!DATA").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:B2"), CopyToRange:=Range("C1:BJ1"), Unique:= _
    False
```

Comment: Range("'CF Backlog.xls'!DATA").Select  gives me an error. can you suggest me what to do please ? thank you very much

Comment: In `CF Backlog.xls` go to the Name Manager in the Formulas tab and see if the Name `DATA` is there

Comment: Thank you all for your help. i could resolve it. the problem was in Range("'CF Backlog.xls'!DATA")